# Elixir Guardian custom header verification instead of Authorization

Tags: http-headers, authorization, elixir, guardian

I have two tokens coming to my Endpoint method. one with inside the key of `Authorization` and another one inside `App-token` but couldn't find any docs/support or anything to workaround this. what is the possible workaround to validate/verify both tokens

I see this option 
`plug(Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader, claims: %{"typ" => "access"}, realm: "Bearer")` for realm but not of `custom header name`
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [recent PR](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/pull/597) for an upcoming Guardian release (post 1.1.0) will allow you to support token verification on any header. A custom header can be verified by plugging `Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader` like so:

```
plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader,
  header_name: CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME,
  realm: :none,
  claims: %{"typ" => "access"}
```

where `CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME` is the name of the header to search within, which in your specific case is "App-token".

Other tokens found within the `Authorization` header and with a default ["realm"](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/issues/464) can leave out the `header_name` option, like so:

```
plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader, claims: %{"typ" => "access"}
```